# Logic Apps not visible under Azure API management

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I got 2 Azure subscription under 1 account. I do experience strange behavior around Azure API management when creating new API for Azure LogicApps. Here is the scenario
I got Subscription A and Subscription B (sub A/sub B from now).
I got Resource Group A in sub A and Resource Group B in sub B (rg A and rg B from now)
Both resource groups are in the same region.
I got Azure Managed API service in rg B.
 I have deployed all the services needed by the solution into rg B and the same region. So API and Logic App and other supporting services are only in rg B and same region.
What is happening that if I want to create new API for LogicApp in the gui when I pick browse to pick the LogicApp the list is empty. None of the Logic Apps is showing off even if they are in the same subscription and resource group.
When I'll try deployment of the Logic App to the rg A on the sub A or I migrate existing Logic Apps in rg B  from sb B to rg A on sub A. Then I can see the logic apps in new API from LogicApp menu even if i kept the API service under rg B and sub B.
I have tried many things but I cannot crack this out.
Any thoughts will be much appreciated.

Best regards,
quark

Comment: 1) Just wanted to double check that you are selecting the right subscription when doing this from top right corner of the portal                                                                                    2) Also I am quite sure you are doing it correctly but again just to double check that we expose an Logic app that has HTTP endpoint on your APIM                                         3) If both these things are correct then we need to look at portal traces for further troubleshooting. I had given the response on MSDN thread